# Можно ли отследить на какую кнопку submit нажали?

Tags: javascript, html, события

```
<form id="orderForm">
  <button type="submit">Принять заказ</button>
  <button type="submit">Отказаться</button>
</form>
```

Есть две кнопки сабмита, можно ли посмотреть какая из 2-х кнопок инициировала действие?
Если вызвать `.submit(function (event) {})`  Либо таким способом нельзя посмотреть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Понять на какую кнопку нажал можно используя аттрибут value. Содержание аттрибута приходит на сервер вместе с отправленой формой:

```
<form id="orderForm">
  <button type="submit" value="confirm">Принять заказ</button>
  <button type="submit" value="cancel">Отказаться</button>
</form>
```

Или можно сразу повесить нужную функцию на кнопку. Тогда нужна функция будет отрабатываться сразу в браузере:

```
<form id="orderForm">
  <button type="submit" value="accept" onclick="confirm();">Принять заказ</button>
  <button type="submit" value="cancel" onclick="cancel();">Отказаться</button>
</form>
```

Comment: а как атрибут value поможет? можешь написать код, как по нему определять?

Comment: @Grundy В смысле как поможет? На сервере бери и смотри что пришло.

Comment: Стоит добавить, что речь про сервер, возможно автора вопроса интересовало именно на клиентской стороне

Comment: @Эникейщик а как это сделать? Через массив POST? Если да, то тогда нужно получается дать имена submit'ам

Comment: @JustLearn Так об этом в ответе и написано :)

Comment: @Эникейщик ну так у Вас нету в ответе атрибутов name для submit'ов

Comment: @JustLearn А чем вас value не устраивает?

Comment: @Эникейщик я попробовал повесить им имена (допустим sumbit1 и submit2). И потом в php скрипте проверяю if (!empty($_POST["submit1"])), то выполняются какие-то действия.  if (!empty($_POST["submit2"]), то выполняются другие действия. Но это не работает

Comment: @Эникейщик можете, пожалуйста, подсказать как с помощью value это проверить? Я не знаю как это сделать

Comment: @Эникейщик насколько я знаю, чтобы проверить value, надо элементу дать name. А потом через POST проверять. А как это сделать без name?

Comment: @JustLearn ``$_POST['value']`` разве не работает? Если нет, то просто добавьте в тэг еще аттрибуты ``name="foo"``, ``name="bar"``

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104956/discussion-between-justlearn-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Этот код ответит на все ваши вопросы:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', (e) => {
    ...
    var submitter = $(e.originalEvent.submitter);
    ...
});
```

При событии submit получаем сабмиттера (нашу кнопку), а дальше делаем с ней, что хотим. Например я беру у нее атрибуты name и value и добавляю в форм-дату, все просто

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]